# Laravel 6 redirect user based on their roles not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I used the authentication system built in Laravel 6. I can't seem to redirect the users based on their roles.

These are my columns in users table:

- username
- password
- email
- roleid

In my LoginController, I added this code:

```
public function redirectTo(){

    // User role
    $role = Auth::user()->roleid; 

    // Check user role
    switch ($role) {
        case 1:
                return '/';
            break;
        case 2:
                return '/application/candidates';
            break; 
    }
}
```

When I tried to login using different credentials with different roles, I always end up on the root route.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you sure your code is getting to this point and that you aren't being redirected earlier on, e.g. by middleware?

Comment: Hi, yup. When I tried to place dd inside redirectTo() method, I was able to get the value of roleid. But when I revert back to the original code, it always redirect to root route after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
return redirect('/');
```

instead of

```
return '/';
```